# ls elementary mathematical equality essentially a self-identity statement?

Tags: logic

In a lot of places equality is defined that for two expressions A=B, A=B means that A and B have the same value (A=B). This relationship seems strange as we are slightly abusing use/mention, if '=' denotes a relationship between expressions then in '1+1=2' '1+1' and '2' are denoting themselves.

Doing this seems a little bit strange considering we generally use '2' and '1+1' to denote values themselves.

If we treat equality as a relationship a mathematical object has with itself, it is not that useful, however the variety of the names and what they inform us of is, for example x+1=2 is equivalent to 2=2 but the former is more interesting.

In this way, is the elementary mathematical use of the equals sign  essentially just an identity statement? (Ignoring the intricacies of the idea that different objects that we equate aren't always mathematically the same due to their construction, as I usually get linked [this article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiO5tifu-X-AhWSecAKHbhpBlMQFnoECAoQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpeople.math.harvard.edu%2F%7Emazur%2Fpreprints%2Fwhen_is_one.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3_EzAdB0Ll98eIYYV4dLzi) and it's not really what I'm asking).

Comment: Equalty sign denotes a relation between entities, eithe phyical objects, numbers or expressions. When we write a statement, it must be clear if we use words to speak of physical objects or of linguistic expression. If not, use quotation marks to avoid ambiguities.

Comment: "Rose is red" Vs "rose has four letters". See use Vs mention.

Comment: "1+1" and "2" are two *expressions* denoting the same [number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number) but they are not the same [*numeral*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_(linguistics)) (i.e. name for number).

Comment: Compare with "Napoleon is the First Emperor of France" where "is" can be read as "is equal to".

Comment: See [your previous post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/95272/how-does-use-mention-apply-to-formulas) regarding use-mention as well as your post [Is '=' or 'equals to' a relationship between Mathematical objects](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586307/is-or-equals-to-a-relationship-between-mathematical-objects) as well as your post [Is '=' a relationship between the objects or their expressions?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/94350/is-a-relationship-between-the-objects-or-their-expressions)

Comment: Not quite. It is the relation of co-extension for mathematical expressions, this is spelled out in the [axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) of ZFC. It is only when = is *interpreted* on a domain that it becomes the relation of self-identity for the interpreting sets (extensions). So 2=1+1 reflects that   {∅, {∅}} and {∅} ∪ {{∅}} must be interpreted by co-extensional  sets, i.e. sets with the same elements. "The evening star is the morning star" is an analogous use of "is" in the natural language.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Although *'rose has four letters'* is understandable, I would argue it's technically wrong. To make it correct, you need quotes around the word "rose": *'"rose" has four letters'*

Comment: @Stef - agreed. But I've written " When we write a statement, it must be clear if we use words to speak of physical objects or of linguistic expression." When in everyday speaking we write "Rose has four letters" also children understand that we are speaking of the name of the flower. The same with mathematics: if we write the expression  "1+1=2" every mathematician understand that we are computing with numbers (use) and not working about syntax (mention).

Comment: ChatGPT? Is that you?

Comment: In a formal context, = is a parameter/logical symbol that may or may not be available to a first order language. For set theory, you can do away with = and just work with the 2 place predicate "element of".

Comment: @BobaFit IKR? This poster posts almost the same exact question over and over and over again, barely registers responses, and I started getting that vibe too. I remember being asked a few times by this site if I was a robot, I wonder if Confused is getting those prompts too, and how it's getting around them.

Comment: @Conifold I'm inclined to disagree. If you regard logic as more fundamental than set theory (which I do) and if you do logic *with identity* (which is common) then the identity predicate is a logical constant and does not need interpretation on a domain. In that case, the answer to the question is "yes": the equality symbol used by mathematicians is the self-identity predicate in logic.

Comment: @Bumble Fundamentality aside, I am also inclined to regard connectives and quantifiers as logical universals not needing an interpretation in most mathematical contexts. But not equality. Mathematicians are inclined to use = variably and interpret it in different ways. Extensionality in ZFC is a semantic constraint on its interpretations that has little to do with logic as such, and ZFC is often reformulated without =. Also, as I see it, self-identity by itself simply misses the point of mathematicians' use of =, which is to mark distinct intensions ("constructions") as co-extensional.

Comment: Is it the case that " x+1 = 2" and "2=2" are identical statements? The second one is a genuine ( though tautological) proposition. The first one is an open sentence that is not entirely meaningful without quantification, and , therefore, that has no truth value. Adding the universal quantifier would make it false. Adding the existential one ( " for some x, x+1=2") would make it true , but still not identical to " 2=2"

Comment: 1 + 1 = 2 and also 2 = 2. What do you make of that?

Answer (score 0):

There are actually lots of different equality/equivalence relations one can define (in the following simply R to avoid any associations you might have with the symbol =). They all have in common:

- reflexivity (xRx for every element x)
- symmetry (xRy => yRx for every element x,y)
- transitivity (xRy, yRz => xRz)

= is overloaded in mathematics, sometimes it denotes identity, but not always. When two expressions are compared, a+b = c+d actually means equality between the numbers the expression evaluates to.

Equality of a program or an expression might range from: evaluates to the same thing, computes the same function, computes the same function AND does so with the same complexity (for various measures of complexity).

An equality between logical sentences means, or might mean, the worlds that make them true are identical, not the sentence itself.